# “I have tested positive…” or “I have ‘been’ tested positive…”?

Tags: tense, present-tense

> 1. I have tested positive for the COVID-19.
> 2. I have *been* tested positive for the COVID-19.

Which one is correct here?

Comment: Use the definite article in "test positive for **the** Coronavirus” but w/o the article before a *disease*, e.g. “test positive for COVID-19” "Test positive for AIDS/cancer/dengue”

Answer (score 1):

> **Test** *verb* **1.5** *no object, with complement* Produce a specified result in a medical test, especially a drugs test or AIDS test.
> *‘he tested positive for steroids during the race’* ( [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/test) )

"I have tested positive" is correct.

"I have been tested positive" sounds awkward and is a much less common usage ( [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+tested+positive%2Chave+been+tested+positive&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20tested%20positive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20tested%20positive%3B%2Cc0) ).

[image]